# Catching data from mysql with php sending through ajax to js and filling table

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I've started working on quite big project.
   Concept: Some1 inserts data to mysql. Other people gets data live on their screen(table)
I had my code working, but I was filling the tables in php and as I understand it is not good for bandwidth, so I'm trying to catch data from mysql with php code, send it to js, which would then format/fill the table (setinterval is running). But my table isn't filling and I'm out of ideas.
 I'm new to js, so if You see anything wrong let me know! Thank You!

PHP:

```
<?php
$rows = array();
$con = mysql_connect("where","who","pass");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("dbname", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Brokers");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $rows[] = $r;
}
mysql_close();
print json-encode($rows);
?>
```

JS:

```
    function fetchData()
{
    $.ajax({
         url: 'brokers.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: createTable(rows)
    })

}
function createTable(rows)
{
    var flowTable = '<table id="resultTable">'
    for (var i=0; i< rows.length; i++){
        flowTable += '<tr class="filterthis height20">',
        flowTable += '<td class="companyname width120">',
        flowTable += rows[i].company_name + '</td>',
        flowTable += '<td class="width180">' ,
        flowTable += rows[i].address + '</td>',
        flowTable += '<td class="width70">' ,
                .........SOME MORE...........
        flowTable += '</tr>';
    }
    flowTable += '</table>';
    $("#here").innerHTML = flowTable;
}
function starttimer(){
  interval = setInterval("fetchData()",1000);
}
```

starttimer();

Comment: First thing I noticed is 'json-encode' in your PHP - it should be json_encode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found a solution.

Corrections to script
JS:

```
function fetchData(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'brokers.php', //where are we sending request
        dataType: 'json',
        success: createTable //where are we transfering data from php ajax request
    })
}

var createTable = function(data){
    rows = jQuery.parseJSON(data) //creates object from information sent from php
    $.each(rows, function(key,value){  //for each row from php does things You want
        $("#Somediv").html = value.owner_name
        //and etc.
    }
}
```

brokers.php:

```
$con = mysql_connect();    
if (!$con) {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db('somedb');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE something=66");
while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ //for each row which = our $result query
   $rows[]=$row;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
mysql_close($con);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is `json_encode` with an underscore not a dash that you have `json-encode`.

Also use:

```
interval = setInterval(fetchData, 1000);
```

Instead of:

```
interval = setInterval("fetchData()",1000);
```

Comment: Change those too, thank You, but still no information in the table

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you're essentially setting your "success" handler to "undefined". This is because you have `success: createTable(rows)` which is actually calling the function and setting its return value ("undefined") as the handler.

Instead, you will want something more like:

```
success: function(data) {
    createTable(data);
}
```

Of course, since the handler is (I *think*) passed the data as the first argument, you could accomplish the same thing via:

```
success: createTable
```

Comment: How will he pass the `data` argument in your last example ?

Comment: The second example is equivalent to the first. They both assume that the "data" is passed as the first argument by the jQuery framework.

Comment: Change it, but still no content in table. But after inspecting the page running, script is sending the request and by size of it (6kb while the php is just 423bytes) I think it is receiving it, something else is in the way. Maybe data is not going outside ajax request?

Comment: Check that the response from the server is coming with an OK status (200). Add an error handler function to your ajax call (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) so that you can at least `alert()` yourself of any errors. Also, `alert()` your `data` or something so you can take a look at the response content (after being parsed by jQuery).